# Is it possible to enable real-time denoising on non-RTX card?

Tags: rendering, denoise

I downloaded blender 2.83 and one of it's new features is realtime Optix viewport denoising. I don't have such option anywhere because I have non-RTX card (GTX 970). Is it possible to edit some lines of codes to get it anyways?

I found this forum where people are editing some .cpp files but I have no clue how do I compile my own version of Blender: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/blender-2-8-cycles-optix-on-non-rtx-card/11224

Thanks for tips.

Comment: Hi. Surely you've answered your own question with the link to devtalk you provided? If the question is how to build blender then I'm afraid that's [off-topic](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399/can-we-please-reconsider-allowing-qa-regarding-blender-build-problems).

Comment: I was wondering if there's any other way than compiling blender from source